# Get printer trays from DevMode

Tags: printing, tray, dev-mode

In my application I pop a print dialog box that (among other things) enables a user to select the print tray for the front page and a print tray for other pages. I then get the DevMode from the printer object:

```
LPDEVMODE  pDevMode  = (LPDEVMODE)::GlobalLock(pPrinter->hDevMode);
```

When I look at the DevMode structure I can get the default source:

```
m_pDevMode->dmDefaultSource
```

which is the 'Other Pages' selection, but I can't get the tray number of the first page selection. Any ideas how I can obtain both tray numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered it's not possible because the settings are driver-specific.